terser-webpack-plugin and uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
Since webpack 4 is using terser-webpack-plugin by default in production mode or when we specify -p argument which is a shortcut for specifying  --optimize-minimize --define process.env.NODE_ENV="production" , in both of these cases it uses terser-webpack-plugin for minimizing JS bundle.
Now my question is if someone did not go through the documentation or might have missed it somehow (which actually happened in a major application), and specified uglifyjs-webpack-plugin in the plugin array like this
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin([TARGET_SERVER], {
        root: BASE_PATH + '/' + OUTPUT_PATH
      }),
      new UglifyJsPlugin(),
   ]

Now this plugin also do the same thing which is optimizing the bundle, now we have specified both of the plugins, one is used by default and another one we specified in plugin array (if it would have been specified as optimization.minimizer , it would have overridden the behavior of terser plugin) , but what will happen in this case
Now in my case what happened is that, it was configured like this, and was working fine for last 3 years , and suddenly it started giving error which is stated in this question, i have already solved it by removing UglifyJsPlugin from the plugin array
Please help me to understand what could have caused this problem

With almost same setup and With webpack5 also it is not working Since July 18
minify: TerserPlugine.UglifyJsMinify.
Seems this minify option is broken from that day.
Once we remove minify options it works properly or use TerserMinify
